# Merging two Vuelidate objects into a single object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, merge, vuelidate

I have two vuelidate objects:

```
obj1 =
        {
           "name":{
              "required":false,
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":true,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 "required":{
                    "type":"requiredIf"
                 }
              }
           },
           "email":{
              "email":true,
              "required":true,
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":false,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 "email":{
                    "type":"email"
                 },
                 "required":{
                    "type":"requiredIf"
                 }
              }
           },
           "shipping":{
              "required":true,
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":false,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 "required":{
                    "type":"requiredIf"
                 }
              }
           },
           "company":{
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":false,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 
              }
           },
           "country":{
              "required":true,
              "$model":{
                 "label":"",
              },
              "$invalid":false,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 "required":{
                    "type":"requiredIf"
                 }
              }
           },
           "city":{
              "required":false,
              "minLength":false,
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":true,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 "required":{
                    "type":"requiredIf"
                 },
                 "minLength":null
              }
           },
           "$model":{
              "name":"",
              "email":"",
              "shipping":"",
              "company":"",
              "country":{
                 "label":"",
              },
              "city":""
           },
           "$invalid":true,
           "$dirty":false,
           "$anyDirty":false,
           "$error":false,
           "$anyError":false,
           "$pending":false,
           "$params":{
              "name":null,
              "email":null,
              "shipping":null,
              "company":null,
              "country":null,
              "city":null
           }
        }
```

```
obj2 =
        {
           "address":{
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":false,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 
              }
           },
           "zipCode":{
              "required":true,
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":false,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 "required":{
                    "type":"requiredIf"
                 }
              }
           },
           "mobile":{
              "required":false,
              "minLength":false,
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":true,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 "required":{
                    "type":"requiredIf"
                 },
                 "minLength":null
              }
           },
           "$model":{
              "address":"",
              "zipCode":"",
              "mobile":"",
           },
           "$invalid":true,
           "$dirty":false,
           "$anyDirty":false,
           "$error":false,
           "$anyError":false,
           "$pending":false,
           "$params":{
              "address":null,
              "zipCode":null,
              "mobile":null,
           }
        }
```

I know for a fact that the keys in **object 1** are not present in the **object 2** and I wanted a resultant object which is a combination of both the objects.

Now, I have tried multiple ways to solve this

for example :

```
{...obj1, "address": this.obj2.address, "mobile": this.obj2.mobile, "zipCode": this.obj2.zipCode }
```

This results in the following resultant object:

```
{
           "name":{
              "required":false,
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":true,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 "required":{
                    "type":"requiredIf"
                 }
              }
           },
           "email":{
              "email":true,
              "required":true,
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":false,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 "email":{
                    "type":"email"
                 },
                 "required":{
                    "type":"requiredIf"
                 }
              }
           },
           "shipping":{
              "required":true,
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":false,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 "required":{
                    "type":"requiredIf"
                 }
              }
           },
           "company":{
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":false,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{

              }
           },
           "country":{
              "required":true,
              "$model":{
                 "label":"",
              },
              "$invalid":false,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 "required":{
                    "type":"requiredIf"
                 }
              }
           },
           "city":{
              "required":false,
              "minLength":false,
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":true,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 "required":{
                    "type":"requiredIf"
                 },
                 "minLength":null
              }
           },
           "address":{
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":false,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{

              }
           },
           "zipCode":{
              "required":true,
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":false,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 "required":{
                    "type":"requiredIf"
                 }
              }
           },
           "mobile":{
              "required":false,
              "minLength":false,
              "$model":"",
              "$invalid":true,
              "$dirty":false,
              "$anyDirty":false,
              "$error":false,
              "$anyError":false,
              "$pending":false,
              "$params":{
                 "required":{
                    "type":"requiredIf"
                 },
                 "minLength":null
              }
           }
           "$model":{
              "name":"",
              "email":"",
              "shipping":"",
              "company":"",
              "country":{
                 "label":"",
              },
              "city":"",
           },
           "$invalid":true,
           "$dirty":false,
           "$anyDirty":false,
           "$error":false,
           "$anyError":false,
           "$pending":false,
           "$params":{
              "name":null,
              "email":null,
              "shipping":null,
              "company":null,
              "country":null,
              "city":null
           }
        }
```

The root objects do get merged but the **$model** of the main object only shows the keys of obj1, similarly the **$params** of the main object also only displays properties of obj1, which ultimately results in the **$invalid** returning true.

I understand that since $model and $params are the shared keys in both the objects that's why in my case the first object takes precedence over the second, how do I make sure both these properties as well share the same keys from both the objects?

For a bit of context, the obj2 is coming from a child component, and obj1 is created in the parent component, now from the parent component both the objects must be passed as a single object containing all the properties.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if obj1/2 share properties/keys?

Comment: I understand the idea of precedence using the spread operator, but in my case, none of the objects would share any properties/keys

Comment: But they do share keys/properties?

Comment: Yes they do, my bad I meant the properties i.e name, email..., but that's correct there are some shared properties such as $model and $params, I need them to also be merged into a single property containing keys from both the objects

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could try this piece of code

```
Object.keys(obj2).forEach(key => {
    if(key == '$model' || key == '$params') {
        Object.keys(obj2[key]).forEach(subKey => {
            obj1[key][subKey] = obj2[key][subKey]
        })
    } else 
    obj1[key] = obj2[key];
})
```

Comment: I've already tried using the spread operator, it is not useful as I've mentioned in the question.

Comment: Well ofc it would cause problems because you have the same keys in both the objects soo....

Comment: That's correct, since $model and $params are the shared keys the first object in my case takes precedence, but then again that's my question, how to get the $model and $params to share keys from both the objects.

Comment: okay, so I guess you want to merge all the keys of obj1 and obj2 and also you want to merge the keys of $model and $params of both the objects in a single key right?

Comment: So something like $params would be "$params":{
              "name":null,
              "email":null,
              "shipping":null,
              "company":null,
              "country":null,
              "city":null,
               "address":null,
              "zipcode":null,
              "mobile":null
           }

Comment: Yes, that's correct!